# Netbeans Platform

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

Im about to start a project for the Netbeans platform. Anyone recommend books or tutorials that they have used and found useful?

Edit:

It is a swing application that has already been developed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apart from the tutorials on the NetBeans website, I like this book:

http://www.packtpub.com/article/netbeans-platform-6-9-working-with-swing-actions

Also make sure you monitor Geertjan's Blog at
http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/

He regularly posts interesting articles about the NetBeans platform.

And of course the NetBeans forum at:
http://forums.netbeans.org/platform-users.html

Comment: I recently bought the book noted in your linked article and am currently working through it. It's okay'ish. It's certainly helped me to understand the concepts behind Lookup and Nodes much better than any online doc I found. Irritatingly, Yoda code the author writes a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can try attending one of the Netbeans [Certifications](http://edu.netbeans.org/courses/nbplatform-certified-training/) to quickly learn the basics of NetBeans Platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a body of Swing code that was not developed with NetBeans, it can be bumpy.

NetBeans manages wysiwyg editing of GUI components by storing data in .form files. So, if you create a JDialog named Foo.java, NetBeans will create an accompanying Foo.form that contains details about how the various components are laid out.

NetBeans will not let you use the GUI builder on a file that does not have an accompanying .form file. You'll need to use the [Form Generator](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormGeneratingFormFile) utility to create a .form file from the .java file.

Comment: Fortunately, most of it was developed in Netbeans. Not every GUI class created though was built using the GUI editor. I created some by hand, so they do not have .form file.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with Netbeans for quite some time in the past.
Your question is a bit vague. what are your plans for the IDE, are you planning to work on swing, java EE, perhaps not even Java.
I would recommend you go over this page, which is more of a portal offered by Netbeans team.
Find it [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html).
Let me know if you need something more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean this in a nasty way if it comes out that way, but quoting "netbeans" and "tutorials" and/or "guides" and "examples" will get you where you need to be most of the time in google. Not many people use quotes when searching and I always find what I need by quoting. Plus as I do some odd tutorials I assume that many others use meta tags that look similar as follows:

```
<meta name="description" lang="en" content="NetBeans 7 install Ubuntu thejarbar.org"/>
            <meta name="description" lang="no" content="installere NetBeans 7 på Windows thejarbar.org"/>
            <meta name="SearchDescription" lang="en" content="NetBeans 7 Ubuntu install thejarbar.org"/>
            <meta name="SearchDescription" lang="no" content="installere NetBeans 7 på Ubuntu thejarbar.org"/>
            <meta name="keywords" lang="en" content="thejarbar.org, thejartender, NetBeans 7, Ubuntu , install, setup,
            tutorial, example, guide, how, to, tutorial, instructions"/>
            <meta name="keywords" lang="no" content="thejarbar.org, thejartender, NetBeans 7, mvn, installere, lære,
            instruksjon, veiledning, guide, eksempel, tutorial"/>
```

Please note the keywords.

Also, I can recommend JEE5 development with Netbeans 6, but I must say that it certainly did not cater for all my NetBeans needs and I wouldn't focus too much on getting too tied down to an IDE, especially with Maven around (from a Java perspective).

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22netbeans%22+6+%22book%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 0):

**JDK Path Setting:**

Follow the given steps below to set the PATH

1. After installing jdk, right click “My Computer” icon
2. Choose “Properties” from context menu
3. Click “Advanced” tab and the click ‘Environment Variable’
4. In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value. For example, if you have installed jdk in C drive then path may be in the form   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin
5. You will have to give your own path in which you have installed jdk.
6. Open Command prompt window, and run your java code.

***Compiling and running code***
After installing jdk and path setting correctly, you can now compile and run your code on command prompt.
In order to compile the code, you have to use javac command. You can use this command as follow:
**javac filename.java**

After successfully compiling code, you can now run the code. You have to use java command to run the code. You can use the run command as follow:
***java filename***